# How to create relationship between two tables with revisions using Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

So I am in the process of redesigning a small database (and potentially a much larger one) but want to show the value of using revisions / history of the business objects.  I am switching the data from Access to MSSQL 2008.

I am having a lot of internal debate on what version of "revision history" to use in the design itself - and thought I had decided to add a "RevisionId" to all tables.

With this design - adding a RevisionId to all tables we would like tracked - what would be the best way to create Navigational Properties and Relationships between two tables such as

```
| Vendor | VendorContact |
```

where a Vendor can have multiple contacts.  The Contacts themselves will be under revision.  Will it require custom extensions or am I over thinking this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So presumably your key for the Contact table would now be a (generated unique ID + a Revision Id).

And there will be a FK relationship between Vendor and Contact using just the unique ID.  So it will be a 1:many mapping.

And a simple request to get the current contact will become `vendor.Contacts.OrderByDescending(c => c.RevisionId).First()` or you can get the entire revision history for that contact if you want.

OR are you trying to track how that contact has changed over time (i.e. it was person A and not it's person B)? i.e. does the relationship itself need to have a RevisionId on it?

Or are you perhaps trying to track both revisions to the relationship AND revisions to the contact it points to?

```
vendor.VendorContacts.OrderBy...().First().Contact.OrderBy...().First()
```

This could get ugly pretty fast!

Comment: Ha, yes it could get very ugly fast! But you were right on the first one.  But yes, this is a good approach. Thanks.  

Is there a way to add such a custom navigation property in the EF designer?  When I have the key from both RevisionId and ContactId - the relationship wants to map the RevisionId of the Vendor to the RevisionId of the Contact.